# awk print lines until next match on the same line

Tags: awk

I have the following type of data file:

```
            0.033333  0.000000  0.000000
  -46.956  -46.956  -23.678  -23.677  -23.055  -23.054  -22.974  -22.974   -8.033   -8.032
   -7.375   -7.356   -7.182   -7.159   -6.695   -6.661   -6.628   -6.598   -4.477   -4.477
   -4.470   -4.462   -4.387   -4.380    3.799    3.800    5.939    5.960    6.116    6.117
    6.625    6.642    7.648    7.651    7.686    7.687    8.077    8.078    8.123    8.126
    8.478    8.497    8.550    8.552   11.625   11.626   12.652   12.653   12.722   12.726
   13.860   13.864   14.291   14.293   14.966   15.046   17.063   17.252   18.011   18.015
            0.016667  0.000000  0.000000
  -46.956  -46.956  -23.677  -23.677  -23.055  -23.054  -22.974  -22.974   -8.037   -8.036
   -7.371   -7.361   -7.177   -7.165   -6.686   -6.669   -6.620   -6.605   -4.476   -4.475
   -4.471   -4.465   -4.385   -4.382    3.811    3.812    5.942    5.952    6.115    6.115
    6.629    6.638    7.651    7.653    7.688    7.689    8.072    8.073    8.122    8.123
    8.491    8.501    8.556    8.556   11.612   11.612   12.665   12.665   12.730   12.733
   13.835   13.837   14.288   14.289   14.991   15.031   17.132   17.225   18.053   18.055
            0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
  -46.956  -46.956  -23.677  -23.677  -23.055  -23.055  -22.974  -22.974   -8.038   -8.038
   -7.366   -7.366   -7.172   -7.172   -6.678   -6.678   -6.613   -6.613   -4.475   -4.475
   -4.469   -4.469   -4.384   -4.384    3.816    3.816    5.946    5.946    6.115    6.115
    6.633    6.633    7.653    7.653    7.689    7.689    8.070    8.070    8.122    8.122
    8.498    8.498    8.558    8.558   11.607   11.607   12.668   12.668   12.735   12.735
   13.827   13.827   14.287   14.287   15.013   15.013   17.186   17.186   18.068   18.068
```

I need to change this to look like this:

```
0.033333  0.000000  0.000000  -46.956  -46.956  -23.678  -23.677  -23.055  -23.054  -22.974  -22.974   -8.033   -8.032   -7.375   -7.356   -7.182   -7.159   -6.695   -6.661   -6.628   -6.598   -4.477   -4.477   -4.470   -4.462   -4.387   -4.380    3.799    3.800    5.939    5.960    6.116    6.117    6.625    6.642    7.648    7.651    7.686    7.687    8.077    8.078    8.123    8.126    8.478    8.497    8.550    8.552   11.625   11.626   12.652   12.653   12.722   12.726   13.860   13.864   14.291   14.293   14.966   15.046   17.063   17.252   18.011   18.015
0.016667  0.000000  0.000000  -46.956  -46.956  -23.677  -23.677  -23.055  -23.054  -22.974  -22.974   -8.037   -8.036   -7.371   -7.361   -7.177   -7.165   -6.686   -6.669   -6.620   -6.605   -4.476   -4.475   -4.471   -4.465   -4.385   -4.382    3.811    3.812    5.942    5.952    6.115    6.115    6.629    6.638    7.651    7.653    7.688    7.689    8.072    8.073    8.122    8.123    8.491    8.501    8.556    8.556   11.612   11.612   12.665   12.665   12.730   12.733   13.835   13.837   14.288   14.289   14.991   15.031   17.132   17.225   18.053   18.055
0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  -46.956  -46.956  -23.677  -23.677  -23.055  -23.055  -22.974  -22.974   -8.038   -8.038   -7.366   -7.366   -7.172   -7.172   -6.678   -6.678   -6.613   -6.613   -4.475   -4.475   -4.469   -4.469   -4.384   -4.384    3.816    3.816    5.946    5.946    6.115    6.115    6.633    6.633    7.653    7.653    7.689    7.689    8.070    8.070    8.122    8.122    8.498    8.498    8.558    8.558   11.607   11.607   12.668   12.668   12.735   12.735   13.827   13.827   14.287   14.287   15.013   15.013   17.186   17.186   18.068   18.068
```

Basically look for the lines with 3 fields only and from there start to remove the line break character until the next line with 3 fields. Also I want to remove all the spaces at the beginning of the line with the 3 fields. Hope this is clearer from the above example.

I have tried the following code:

```
BEGIN {
    ORS=" ";
}
NF==3 {x=NR+6} (NR<=x) {print}
```

Trouble is that I get a completely different result. I don't know how to add a `\n` character before the next pattern match. So I get:

```
0.033333  0.000000  0.000000   -46.956  -46.956  -23.678  -23.677  -23.055  -23.054  -22.974  -22.974   -8.033   -8.032    -7.375   -7.356   -7.182   -7.159   -6.695   -6.661   -6.628   -6.598   -4.477   -4.477    -4.470   -4.462   -4.387   -4.380    3.799    3.800    5.939    5.960    6.116    6.117     6.625    6.642    7.648    7.651    7.686    7.687    8.077    8.078    8.123    8.126     8.478    8.497    8.550    8.552   11.625   11.626   12.652   12.653   12.722   12.726    13.860   13.864   14.291   14.293   14.966   15.046   17.063   17.252   18.011   18.015             0.016667  0.000000  0.000000   -46.956  -46.956  -23.677  -23.677  -23.055  -23.054  -22.974  -22.974   -8.037   -8.036    -7.371   -7.361   -7.177   -7.165   -6.686   -6.669   -6.620   -6.605   -4.476   -4.475    -4.471   -4.465   -4.385   -4.382    3.811    3.812    5.942    5.952    6.115    6.115     6.629    6.638    7.651    7.653    7.688    7.689    8.072    8.073    8.122    8.123     8.491    8.501    8.556    8.556   11.612   11.612   12.665   12.665   12.730   12.733    13.835   13.837   14.288   14.289   14.991   15.031   17.132   17.225   18.053   18.055             0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   -46.956  -46.956  -23.677  -23.677  -23.055  -23.055  -22.974  -22.974   -8.038   -8.038    -7.366   -7.366   -7.172   -7.172   -6.678   -6.678   -6.613   -6.613   -4.475   -4.475    -4.469   -4.469   -4.384   -4.384    3.816    3.816    5.946    5.946    6.115    6.115     6.633    6.633    7.653    7.653    7.689    7.689    8.070    8.070    8.122    8.122     8.498    8.498    8.558    8.558   11.607   11.607   12.668   12.668   12.735   12.735    13.827   13.827   14.287   14.287   15.013   15.013   17.186   17.186   18.068
```

I also don't know how to get rid of all the space characters on the line with the pattern match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
NF==3 { sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")      # remove leading white space
        printf "%s%s",eol,$0         # initially eol="" (undefined)
        eol="\n"                     # next time print this line with a leading "\n" (to close out previous line) 
        next}
      { printf "%s%s",OFS,$0 }       # OP will need to decide if the extra OFS is needed here or can be removed
END   { print "" }                   # terminate last line of output with a "\n"
' file
```

This generates:

```
0.033333  0.000000  0.000000   -46.956  -46.956  -23.678  -23.677  -23.055  -23.054  -22.974  -22.974   -8.033   -8.032    -7.375   -7.356   -7.182   -7.159   -6.695   -6.661   -6.628   -6.598   -4.477   -4.477    -4.470   -4.462   -4.387   -4.380    3.799    3.800    5.939    5.960    6.116    6.117     6.625    6.642    7.648    7.651    7.686    7.687    8.077    8.078    8.123    8.126     8.478    8.497    8.550    8.552   11.625   11.626   12.652   12.653   12.722   12.726    13.860   13.864   14.291   14.293   14.966   15.046   17.063   17.252   18.011   18.015
0.016667  0.000000  0.000000   -46.956  -46.956  -23.677  -23.677  -23.055  -23.054  -22.974  -22.974   -8.037   -8.036    -7.371   -7.361   -7.177   -7.165   -6.686   -6.669   -6.620   -6.605   -4.476   -4.475    -4.471   -4.465   -4.385   -4.382    3.811    3.812    5.942    5.952    6.115    6.115     6.629    6.638    7.651    7.653    7.688    7.689    8.072    8.073    8.122    8.123     8.491    8.501    8.556    8.556   11.612   11.612   12.665   12.665   12.730   12.733    13.835   13.837   14.288   14.289   14.991   15.031   17.132   17.225   18.053   18.055
0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   -46.956  -46.956  -23.677  -23.677  -23.055  -23.055  -22.974  -22.974   -8.038   -8.038    -7.366   -7.366   -7.172   -7.172   -6.678   -6.678   -6.613   -6.613   -4.475   -4.475    -4.469   -4.469   -4.384   -4.384    3.816    3.816    5.946    5.946    6.115    6.115     6.633    6.633    7.653    7.653    7.689    7.689    8.070    8.070    8.122    8.122     8.498    8.498    8.558    8.558   11.607   11.607   12.668   12.668   12.735   12.735    13.827   13.827   14.287   14.287   15.013   15.013   17.186   17.186   18.068   18.068
```

Comment: your solution is perfect and I can also understand to an extent. I have realized I made a wrong assumption regarding the input file though. the first line has a sort of header but it is longer than 3 fields and I assumed that it wouldn't matter. however it does since the first line now appears in the output too. I tried to modify the condition as `(NR>1 && NF==3)` but it does nothing. How can I ignore the first line with your solution?

Comment: I got it! I added above the `NF==3` line the following: `NR==1 {next}`. Is this a good way to do it?

Comment: yes, `NR==1 { next }` should be sufficient to skip the 1st line

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v ORS= '
    NF==3 {
        if (NR>1) print "\n"
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*/,"")
    }
    1;
    END { print "\n" }
' file
```

- unset default newline for print (`OFS=`)
- when 3-field line detected

  - print a newline (unless this is first line)
  - strip leading whitespace
- default print (`1;`) - with no trailing newline
- print final newline at the end

This code assumes all lines have leading whitespace (as shown in the sample input), so that no field separator is needed on joined lines.

---

Your original code is actually not far from working:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { ORS=" " } # or maybe ORS=""
    NF==3 {
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*/,"") # strip leading whitespace
        x = NR+6
    }
    NR<=x { print }
    NR==x { printf "\n" }
' file
```

---

An even simpler solution if we know that the 3-field lines always have much more leading whitespace than any other line (e.g. 8 or more):

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]{8,}' 'gsub(/\n/,"")' file
```

- set input record separator to be lots of spaces
- strip all embedded newlines
- implicit print will append a trailing newline

Note that the first (empty) record is conveniently elided because gsub fails (no newlines removed) and so does not trigger the implicit print.

Another note: This requires a version of awk that supports multi-character `RS` (e.g. `gawk`, `busybox`; but not `mawk`, `original-awk`).

Final note: This method, while shorter code, appears to run significantly more slowly (about 10% of the speed of the first version).

---

For **super**-slow (about 1% the speed of the first awk version), and if squeezing whitespace is not a problem, there is also the extremely compact:

```
<file xargs -n63
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you always have 7 lines per record, all you need is this, using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='([^\n]+\n){7}' -v ORS= '{$0=RT; $1=$1} 1' file
0.033333 0.000000 0.000000 -46.956 -46.956 -23.678 -23.677 -23.055 -23.054 -22.974 -22.974 -8.033 -8.032 -7.375 -7.356 -7.182 -7.159 -6.695 -6.661 -6.628 -6.598 -4.477 -4.477 -4.470 -4.462 -4.387 -4.380 3.799 3.800 5.939 5.960 6.116 6.117 6.625 6.642 7.648 7.651 7.686 7.687 8.077 8.078 8.123 8.126 8.478 8.497 8.550 8.552 11.625 11.626 12.652 12.653 12.722 12.726 13.860 13.864 14.291 14.293 14.966 15.046 17.063 17.252 18.011 18.015
0.016667 0.000000 0.000000 -46.956 -46.956 -23.677 -23.677 -23.055 -23.054 -22.974 -22.974 -8.037 -8.036 -7.371 -7.361 -7.177 -7.165 -6.686 -6.669 -6.620 -6.605 -4.476 -4.475 -4.471 -4.465 -4.385 -4.382 3.811 3.812 5.942 5.952 6.115 6.115 6.629 6.638 7.651 7.653 7.688 7.689 8.072 8.073 8.122 8.123 8.491 8.501 8.556 8.556 11.612 11.612 12.665 12.665 12.730 12.733 13.835 13.837 14.288 14.289 14.991 15.031 17.132 17.225 18.053 18.055
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -46.956 -46.956 -23.677 -23.677 -23.055 -23.055 -22.974 -22.974 -8.038 -8.038 -7.366 -7.366 -7.172 -7.172 -6.678 -6.678 -6.613 -6.613 -4.475 -4.475 -4.469 -4.469 -4.384 -4.384 3.816 3.816 5.946 5.946 6.115 6.115 6.633 6.633 7.653 7.653 7.689 7.689 8.070 8.070 8.122 8.122 8.498 8.498 8.558 8.558 11.607 11.607 12.668 12.668 12.735 12.735 13.827 13.827 14.287 14.287 15.013 15.013 17.186 17.186 18.068 18.06
```

or this using any awk:

```
$ awk '{rec=rec FS $0} !(NR%7){$0=rec; rec=""; $1=$1; print}' file
0.033333 0.000000 0.000000 -46.956 -46.956 -23.678 -23.677 -23.055 -23.054 -22.974 -22.974 -8.033 -8.032 -7.375 -7.356 -7.182 -7.159 -6.695 -6.661 -6.628 -6.598 -4.477 -4.477 -4.470 -4.462 -4.387 -4.380 3.799 3.800 5.939 5.960 6.116 6.117 6.625 6.642 7.648 7.651 7.686 7.687 8.077 8.078 8.123 8.126 8.478 8.497 8.550 8.552 11.625 11.626 12.652 12.653 12.722 12.726 13.860 13.864 14.291 14.293 14.966 15.046 17.063 17.252 18.011 18.015
0.016667 0.000000 0.000000 -46.956 -46.956 -23.677 -23.677 -23.055 -23.054 -22.974 -22.974 -8.037 -8.036 -7.371 -7.361 -7.177 -7.165 -6.686 -6.669 -6.620 -6.605 -4.476 -4.475 -4.471 -4.465 -4.385 -4.382 3.811 3.812 5.942 5.952 6.115 6.115 6.629 6.638 7.651 7.653 7.688 7.689 8.072 8.073 8.122 8.123 8.491 8.501 8.556 8.556 11.612 11.612 12.665 12.665 12.730 12.733 13.835 13.837 14.288 14.289 14.991 15.031 17.132 17.225 18.053 18.055
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -46.956 -46.956 -23.677 -23.677 -23.055 -23.055 -22.974 -22.974 -8.038 -8.038 -7.366 -7.366 -7.172 -7.172 -6.678 -6.678 -6.613 -6.613 -4.475 -4.475 -4.469 -4.469 -4.384 -4.384 3.816 3.816 5.946 5.946 6.115 6.115 6.633 6.633 7.653 7.653 7.689 7.689 8.070 8.070 8.122 8.122 8.498 8.498 8.558 8.558 11.607 11.607 12.668 12.668 12.735 12.735 13.827 13.827 14.287 14.287 15.013 15.013 17.186 17.186 18.068 18.06
```

Comment: if whitespace is irrelevant: `<file xargs -n63` . btw, the gawk seems to print an extraneous trailing newline

Comment: @jhnc I fixed the gawk issue thanks.

Comment: @jhnc you should post that xargs script as a solution, it might be what the OP wants.

Comment: I was mostly joking :-)  xargs will do an echo per record. It looks like it works out to about 1% the speed of, for example, your "any awk"  (btw, your "gawk" version seem to be about 3% the speed of your "any awk")

Comment: thank you for this @EdMorton! this is not always the case with the 7 lines. I used that initial solution for this particular data set but with others I would have to manually change it. I got the solution below and it seems to work regardless of how many rows there are between matches.

Comment: If there aren't always 7 lines in your real data then please edit the example in your question so it also doesn't always have 7 rows.